# An RPC mechanism which handles type hierarchy correctly in java

Tags: java, rpc, hierarchy

I need a mechanism for calling remote methods on server which handles type hierarchy correctly. For example GWT can do this, but my client isn't javascript! By handling type hierarchy, I mean transfering child objects even when the type is declared as a parent class! Suppose we have a class Container:

```
class Parent {
   String name;
}
class Child extends Parent {
   String family;
}

class Container {
   Parent p;
}
```

And I have a method on server with the following signature:

```
void doSomethingImportant(Container c) {}
```

If I call this method on client, and pass an instance of Container, which has an instance of Child as property "p", I expect to get an instance of Child on server too (which would have "family" property)!
GWT handles this without any problem, is there any other technologies that can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a RPC mechanism for this, but I managed to use JSON in order to handle this. I found Gson which is google's API for using JSON in java. It converts objects to JsonElements which can be interpretted as Strings and vice versa.
So the key feature that helped me develop this, was Gson's custom Serializer/Deserializer. I implemented a class which is Serializer and Deserializer for Object, and I send the class name for source class along the class's content:

```
class MySerializerAndDeserializer implements JsonSerializer<Object>, JsonDeserializer<Object>{

public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc,
        JsonSerializationContext context) {
    Class clazz = src.getClass();
    JsonElement serialize = context.serialize(src);
    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
    array.add(new JsonPrimitive(clazz.getName()));
    array.add(serialize);
    return array;
}

public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();
    String asString = array.get(0).getAsString();
    Object deserialize = null;
    try {
        deserialize = context.deserialize(array.get(1).getAsJsonObject(), Class.forName(asString));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return deserialize;
}
}
```

and then I registered MySerializerAndDeserializer for Parent.class:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Parent.class, new MySerializerAndDeserializer());
```

And finally used gson and got the Instance I expected correctly:

```
String json = gson.toJson(container, Container.class);
Container containerFromJson = gson.fromJson(json, Container.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sfnrpc (http://code.google.com/p/sfnrpc) you can specify which type must be used optionally in the class arguments.
Hope this helps.

```
 Object [] objArr = new Object[1];
 TestObject to = new TestObject();
 to.data = "HELLO,";
 objArr[0] = to;

 **Class [] classArr = new Class[1];
 classArr[0] = TestObject.class;**

 TestObject response = (TestObject)rpcc.invoke("#URN1","127.0.0.1:6878","echo",true,60,"", objArr,classArr);
 sl.debug("The response was:"+response.data);
```